# My cell output in VSCode when running a Jupyter Notebook are all gray and I can't fix it

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

I was coding in VSC using Jupyter and I dropped my phone on my keyboard and all of my cells became gray. I'm not sure how to fix it.

I don't know if my file size is too big, or If there are too many plotly graphics in my notebook, but I can't find a way to fix it.

I've tried re-installing the regular/stable version of VSC, installing VSC-Insiders, clearing my cache (I believe I did this correctly via stack posts).

Here's a screenshot of what I am seeing:

[image: Screenshot]

I've attempted to force quit the application (insider and base VSC) and it still occurrs.

Comment: Have you tried just quitting VS Code and reopening the file? I pressed random key combinations for a while and couldn't replicate your screenshot.

Comment: I have, yeah. I don't think it's a resource Issue. I have a M1 Pro, 10-core, 16gb of ram.

Comment: Have you tried changing the theme?

Comment: @wjandrea No joy on the theme change - still the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Generally, the output box will be grayed out only when your jupyter cache is large.

According to [this issue on github](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/114459#issuecomment-814846486), the easiest to get out of this is to delete the Cache folder.

**Windows** `%APPDATA%\Code - Insiders\Code Cache`

**macOS** `$HOME/Library/Application Support/Code - Insiders/Code Cache`

**Linux** `$HOME/.config/Code - Insiders/Code Cache`

You can also try to **clear output**.

[image]

Comment: It's not working for me, still. I don't know if there is some kind of error log or something I can pull up to help diagnose the issue. I deleted the Code Cache folder initially, then deleted all of the cache folders and it still didn't resolve it

Comment: Have you tied use other versions of jupyter extension? I found [a similar issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/11031) which has been solved, you can add your problem on github.

Comment: Cleaning up the .config/Code helped for a few minutes, but then the reported problem showed up again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using a formatting extention. Try turning it off or uninstalling it.

[image]